# Unlist lists of lists in R

Tags: r

I have written a function that builds a decision tree. The output `L` is then a list of lists, where each "leaf" of the list is a subset of the data that reaches the corresponding leaf in the tree. For example, if the tree has 3 leaves, then the output of the function will be the nested list `L` with 3 data.frames

```
List of 2
 $ left :'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ X1: num [1:5] 0.884 0.875 1.175 1.053 0.858
  ..$ X2: num [1:5] 0.996 0.884 0.995 1.029 1.006
  ..$ y : num [1:5] 1 1 1 1 1
 $ right:List of 2
  ..$ left :'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X1: num [1:5] 2.03 1.93 2.07 2.02 2.06
  .. ..$ X2: num [1:5] 1.98 1.95 1.85 2.14 2.11
  .. ..$ y : num [1:5] 3 3 3 3 3
  ..$ right:'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X1: num [1:5] 2.93 2.92 3.02 2.84 2.95
  .. ..$ X2: num [1:5] 2.98 3.06 2.91 3.03 2.89
  .. ..$ y : num [1:5] 2 2 2 2 2
```

How can I combine these data.frames into one data.frame in general, i.e. how can I unlist this list?

Comment: Could you post a small sample of the output (just a few lines from each leaf), e.g. using `dput()`, to make it easier to test solutions?

Comment: @MattAshby I have included a simple example of the output

Comment: The leaves are stored as nested lists. If the goal is to flatten the 3 data frames into 1, how do you imagine preserving the nested information? As a new column?

Comment: The nested structure is something I got because I am using nested functions. Maybe that's not ideal, but if there was a simple way to bind these data frames into one, I would be ok

Comment: Is your only goal to bind these data frames into one, with their current columns? Or do you also want to add additional columns that would express the nested nature of the original data?

Comment: As of right now, binding into one is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a recursive approach. It applies a similar logic to what you would use as a human.

```
flat <- list()
finder <- function(l) {
    for (element in l) {
        if (inherits(element, "data.frame")) {
            flat <<- c(flat, list(element))
        } else {
            finder(element)
        }
    }
    return(flat)
}
```

Once you have run the above, you can call it with `Reduce(rbind, finder(your_list))`

I'm not sure how to approach it without having to use `<<-` so would love feedback from those more knowledgeable than myself.

Comment: You do realize the moment you use `c` unction on a dataframe, it stops being a dataframe? `c` is used to throw away the attributes. ie `c(iris, iris)` will no longer be a dataframe. or even `c(iris)`

Comment: I'm not using it on a dataframe, I'm using it on a list

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the maximum depth of the list is 2 (as shown in your example, you can bind all the rows of the nodes with a depth of 2 with `bind_rows()` from `dplyr`, iterating over all the top-level nodes with `map_dfr()` from `purrr`. In both cases you can use the `.id` argument to create a column to store the name of the leaf and branch (or whatever you want to call them).

```r
tree <- list(
  "left" = data.frame(
    X1 = c(0.884, 0.875, 1.175, 1.053, 0.858),
    X2 = c(0.996, 0.884, 0.995, 1.029, 1.006),
    y = 1
  ),
  "right" = list(
    "left" = data.frame(
      X1 = c(2.03, 1.93, 2.07, 2.02, 2.06),
      X2 = c(1.98, 1.95, 1.85, 2.14, 2.11),
      y = 3
    ),
    "right" = data.frame(
      X1 = c(2.93, 2.92, 3.02, 2.84, 2.95),
      X2 = c(2.98, 3.06, 2.91, 3.03, 2.89),
      y = 2
    )
  )
)

purrr::map_dfr(
  tree, 
  function (x) {
    if (is.data.frame(x)) {
      x
    } else {
      dplyr::bind_rows(x, .id = "leaf")
    }
  }
  , 
  .id = "branch"
)
#>    branch    X1    X2 y  leaf
#> 1    left 0.884 0.996 1  <NA>
#> 2    left 0.875 0.884 1  <NA>
#> 3    left 1.175 0.995 1  <NA>
#> 4    left 1.053 1.029 1  <NA>
#> 5    left 0.858 1.006 1  <NA>
#> 6   right 2.030 1.980 3  left
#> 7   right 1.930 1.950 3  left
#> 8   right 2.070 1.850 3  left
#> 9   right 2.020 2.140 3  left
#> 10  right 2.060 2.110 3  left
#> 11  right 2.930 2.980 2 right
#> 12  right 2.920 3.060 2 right
#> 13  right 3.020 2.910 2 right
#> 14  right 2.840 3.030 2 right
#> 15  right 2.950 2.890 2 right
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>